# how to initial the redux global store preloadedState

Tags: reactjs, redux

this is my app store in react redux when using typescript:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rootReducer from '../reducer/combineReducer';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const logger = createLogger(); 
const initialState = {
    
};

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: [logger, thunk],
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    preloadedState: initialState
});

export default store;
```

now I want to give some initial global data structure in preloadedState, then I tweak the initialState code like this:

```
const initialState = {
    user: {}
};
```

the visual studio code shows error:

```
Type '{ user: {}; }' is not assignable to type '{ readonly [$CombinedState]?: undefined; user?: { user: any; loginUser: {}; } | { loginUser: any; user: {}; } | undefined; }'.
  Types of property 'user' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ user: any; loginUser: {}; } | { loginUser: any; user: {}; } | undefined'.ts(2322)
configureStore.d.ts(45, 5): The expected type comes from property 'preloadedState' which is declared here on type 'ConfigureStoreOptions<CombinedState<{ user: { user: any; loginUser: {}; } | { loginUser: any; user: {}; }; }>, any, Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>[], [...]>'
(property) ConfigureStoreOptions<CombinedState<{ user: { user: any; loginUser: {}; } | { loginUser: any; user: {}; }; }>, any, Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>[], [...]>.preloadedState?: {
    readonly [$CombinedState]?: undefined;
    user?: {
        user: any;
        loginUser: {};
    } | {
        loginUser: any;
        user: {};
    } | undefined;
} | undefined
```

what should I do to add some initial global field define?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the error message:

```
 Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ user: any; loginUser: {}; } | { loginUser: any; user: {}; } | undefined'
```

TypeScript expects the value of `user` to be an object with `user` and `loginUser` fields, but you are giving an empty object instead. Pass these in the object to fix the error.

The [type definition](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore) of `ConfigureStoreOptions` also explains this:

```js
/**
 * The initial state, same as Redux's createStore.
 * You may optionally specify it to hydrate the state
 * from the server in universal apps, or to restore a previously serialized
 * user session. If you use `combineReducers()` to produce the root reducer
 * function (either directly or indirectly by passing an object as `reducer`),
 * this must be an object with the same shape as the reducer map keys.
 */
preloadedState?: DeepPartial<S extends any ? S : S>
```